# DataSet not defined?

Tags: asp.net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim AppName As String = Session("App_Name").ToString()
    Dim username As String = Session("username").ToString()
    Dim password As String = Session("password").ToString()
    Dim ds As DataSet = GContactsImport.GetGmailContacts(AppName, username, password)
    GridView1.DataSource = ds
    GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub
```

how do i fix it??

This is my class file

Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports Google.GData.Contacts
Imports Google.GData.Client
Imports Google.GData.Extensions
Imports Google.Contacts

Public Class Google
    Public Shared Function GetGmailContacts(ByVal AppName As String, ByVal Uname As String, ByVal UPassword As String) As DataSet
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim C2 As New DataColumn()
        C2.DataType = Type.GetType
        C2.ColumnName = "EmailID"
        dt.Columns.Add(C2)
        Dim rs As New RequestSettings(AppName, Uname, UPassword)
        rs.AutoPaging = True
        Dim cr As New ContactsRequest(rs)
        Dim f As Feed(Of Contact) = cr.GetContacts()
        For Each t As Contact In f.Entries
            For Each email As EMail In t.Emails
                Dim dr1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                dr1("EmailID") = email.Address.ToString()
                dt.Rows.Add(dr1)
            Next
        Next
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Return ds
    End Function

End Class

Answer (score 2):

Verify that `DataSet` is in scope (you may need to add an `Import` statement) or, alternatively, fully qualify the `DataSet` references in your code by replacing `Dim ds As DataSet` with `Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet`.

Comment: Add an If statement to check if ds is being set to Nothing??

Comment: If `GContactsImport.GetGmailContacts()` is returning `Nothing` for whatever reason, you would get an error. But I just re-read your title and it is only `DataSet` is undefined, which means #1 is going to be the right thing to go for.

Comment: ya..if i use 'Imports System.Data' the error disappears but i get a new error.. it says "GContactsImport" not defined

Comment: Then try removing `Imports System.Data` and just fully qualify `DataSet` references. Replace `Dim ds As DataSet` with `Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet`. That will achieve the same effect. I will update my answer with this.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you have imported the required namespace for `GContactsImport`? It seems like the `DataSet` issues is hiding the `GContactsImport` problem. Please verify that you have imported everything for `GContactsImport`.

Comment: Imports Google.GData.Contacts
Imports Google.GData.Client
Imports Google.GData.Extensions
Imports Google.Contacts
Imports Google.GData

Comment: i do not know what else to import.

Comment: I presume that you are following this article: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/37275-Import-Gmail-Contacts-into-ASP-NET.aspx I have looked over the documentation and can't even find a reference to `GContactsImport`, which is kind of strange. Could the article, and thus, your code, be outdated?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to reference the `System.Data` assembly from the GAC and `Imports System.Data` (at the top of your file) in order to bring the [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) class into scope.

Comment: if i import system.data it says "GContactsImport" not defined.

Comment: @Monodeep, well then import the namespace into which this custom `GContactsImport` class is defined.

Comment: You might need to reference the System.Data assembly from the GAC??

Comment: @Monodeep, yes the Global Assembly Cache.

Comment: @Monodeep, apparently you've already had it referenced if the error about DataSet disappeared. As far as adding assembly references to a project is concerned you may take a look at the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: ya..if i use 'Imports System.Data' the error disappears but i get a new error.. it says "GContactsImport" not defined.

Comment: @Monodeep, please read my second comment. You need to add `Imports XXXX` where XXXX is the namespace in which this `GContactsImport` class is defined. This is not a standard .NET class, you must be using some third party component, source code or something else. Unfortunately you mentioned nothing about it in your question so it's difficult to help you more. Please read the documentation of the library you are using and see where this class is defined and import the correct namespace.

Comment: i added the class file i am using.does it help??

Comment: @Monodeep, you need to add the namespace. Go to the file containing this class and look at which namespace it is defined. You could also try putting the cursor over the `GContactsImport` and normally a red squiggle should appear and clicking on it will give you the possibility to automatically add the correct namespace.

Comment: this is what i am trying to do...http://sovitmittal.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/import-gmail-contacts-into-asp-net-gridview/

Comment: you need to add the namespace. Go to the file containing this class and look at which namespace it is defined.what do u mean??please explain..i am very new to asp.net.

Comment: @Monodeep, ok, so in the C# example in Step 4 there are a couple of namespaces in the using clause: `Google.GData.Contacts`, `Google.GData.Client`, `Google.GData.Extensions` and `Google.Contacts`. Did you add those? Also I would recommend you reading some basic tutorials about namespaces, assemblies, CLR, ... which are basic notions in .NET before getting into ASP.NET.

Comment: ya i added those namspaces in my class file...bu when i try to add them in my aspx.vb file i get not defined error.

Comment: @Monodeep, you need to reference the assembly you downloaded in the project. Here's how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: any way i can send you the project file??

Comment: if u want we can use teamviewer.

Comment: @Monodeep, please upload your project file on some web site.

Comment: @Monodeep, you seem to have downloaded the latest version of the Google Contact API (v3.0) but are trying to use the `GContactsImport` class which no longer exists. Here's the documentation of how to achieve this in v3.0: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Retrieving You need to use a `ContactsRequest` object.